# Calling Python script in PHP post PHP 5.4

Tags: php, python, mysql

Basically I want to call a simple python script from PHP. I have a PHP page that is adding requests from an html page to a Mysql table, and I'd like this PHP page to call a python script which email administrators to my site once the PHP has finished. I'm currently trying to use the command exec('sudo python /var/www/alertAdmins.py'). However, after reading the PHP documentation it seems that exec requires safe mode, which has been removed as of PHP 5.4 to my understanding. Is there an alternative function I can use? Any workarounds?

Comment: I never heard of exec() requires safe mode. I'm using shell_exec(). Check if the function is disabled. Use for this case phpinfo().

Answer (score 0):

No, [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) does not require Safe Mode.

It used to have additional restrictions when Safe Mode was on, though.

Comment: so, looking into it again, managed to get my php file to run without error using exec. However, the python code doesn't seem to be doing anything. The script should add an entry to a mysql table so that I know it has worked and when I run the after I open the page I don't see this entry in my log. Any thoughts?